Does the rate $\log n$ imply "almost harmonic"?
Let $\{c_k\}$ be a decreasing positive sequence such that $\sum_{k=1}^n c_k \sim \log n$. Does it say $c_k=O(1/k)?$
I have found a reference where it says that the converse is true. I tried to tackle this problem with some Stolz-Cesaro / Tauberian type techniques but no progress so far. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I don't think you can expect this without some kind of monotonicity assumption. Otherwise it seems to me like $c_n$ could potentially "spike" in such a way to make this barely not true while not affecting the partial sums too much.

That's a valid point. Okay, so what if we assume $c_n$ are monotonically decreasing?

@QiaochuYuan I have edited the question.

Maybe there exists an increasing sequence ${n_i}$ of natural numbers such that the sequence ${c_k}$,
where $c_k=2^{-\min{i:n_i\ge k}}$ for each natural number $k$, is a counterexample.

No. Let $N_1 < N_2 < \dots$ be a sufficiently rapidly increasing sequence of positive integers. Define $$c_k = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{N_j} & k \in [N_j+1, N_j\log\log N_j] \\ \frac{1}{k} & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}.$$ Clearly $c_k$ is a positive decreasing sequence that is not $O(\frac{1}{k})$. And it satisfies $\sum_{k \le n} c_k \sim \log n$, since the only deviations from $\frac{1}{k}$ don't contribute much. Indeed, $\sum_{k = N_j+1}^{N_j \log\log N_j} \frac{1}{N_j} = \log\log N_j - 1 = o(\log N_j)$ and $\sum_{k=N_j+1}^{N_j\log\log N_j} \frac{1}{k} \sim \log(N_j\log\log N_j)-\log(N_j) = \log\log\log N_j = o(\log N_j)$.

What exactly do you mean by "sufficiently rapidly increasing?"

@K.defaoite $N_{j+1} \ge 2^{10+N_j\log\log N_j}$.

I'm not convinced yet that your $S_n \sim log(n)$ where $S_n=\sum_{k\leq n} c_k$. Note that, since $c_k \geq \frac{1}{k}$ for
every $k$, so $S_n \geq \sum_{k\leq n} \frac{1}{k}$, and hence $S_n$ cannot be too small. Thus we need to show that $S_n$ cannot be too large, or
in other words that $D_n=S_n-\sum_{k\leq n} \frac{1}{k}$ cannot be too large. Now, $D_n$ is a sum of chunks $D_n=\sum_(j;N_j\leq n} D_{n,j}$
where $D_{n,j}=\sum_{k= N_j+1}^{N_j+\log(\log(N_j))} \frac{1}{k}$. and your argument shows that $D_{n,j}=o(\log(N_j))$.  (to be continued)

(comment, continued) Thus, an individual chunk
is small enough for our purposes. However, it does not seem clear at all (at least to me) that the sum of those small enough chunks is still
small enough. In other words, how do you show that $\sum_{j;N_j\leq n}o(\log(N_j))=o(\log(n))$ ?

@EwanDelanoy Because the $N_j$'s are sufficiently rapidly increasing. You can ensure that $\sum_{j \le J-1} N_j \le \log N_J$ for instance. Therefore, only the largest $N_J \le n$ matters, and of course $\log N_j \le \log n$, so $o(\log N_j) = o(\log N)$.

I see. +1 now that you've convinced me

No. Define $c_n = 2^{-k}$ for $n=4^k$ and $c_n = 1/n$ otherwise. Then $nc_n \to \infty$ as $n$ ranges over powers of $4$ and thus $c_n \ne O(1/n)$, but the partial sums are clearly asymptotic to $\log n$.

Thanks a lot. Can you comment anything if we assume $c_n$ to be monotonically decreasing?

@L-- That'll require some more thought, certainly. BTW it's not exactly polite to edit your question to something different after someone's already answered (although I can understand your inclination as the monotone case is the most interesting).
